# SQL Query to achieve some kind of Left/Right Join with an extra condition

Tags: c#, sql, navision

I am working with MS Navision and have the folowing situation.

2 tables like in the below image and need to produce the result you see below as "Desired". This is needed in order to indentify the rows with NULL values and present them in a report:

TABLE1

```
+---------+-------+  
| Cluster | OGE   |  
+---------+-------+  
| B1309   | A     |  
| B1309   | B     |  
+---------+-------+
```

Table2

```
+--------+---------+-----+  
|  Type  | Cluster | OGE |  
+--------+---------+-----+  
| Liniar | B1309   | A   |  
| 44     | B1309   | A   |  
| 44     | B1309   | B   |  
+--------+---------+-----+
```

Desired

```
+---------+-----+---------+---------+--------+  
| Cluster | OGE |  Type   | Cluster | OGE    |  
+---------+-----+---------+---------+--------+  
| B1309   | A   | Liniar  | B1309   | A      |  
| B1309   | B   | Liniar  | NULL    | NULL   |  
| B1309   | A   | 44      | B1309   | A      |  
| B1309   | B   | 44      | B1309   | B      |  
+---------+-----+---------+---------+--------+
```

This is needed in order to identify **what records from Table1 don't have a corresponding entry in Table2 for each Type**

My tables can have thousands of rows, so this is why I want to find a way to identify this in an efficient way, without looping throw each row..

Do you know at least how something like this is achieved in SQL Server or a programming language, maybe I can implement the logic in NAV?

Thanks

Comment: TIP: You would get a much better response if you have the actual text of the problem in your post instead of linking to a handdrawn image.

Comment: Hi, all right, I'll try to add now the text. I'm struggling to find how can the question be edited :)

Comment: @Andrey there should be small "edit" link under your question (on left side) or you can click this [edit] link

Comment: Done, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Andrey what's the logic behind the `desired` output? Why does the second line contain NULLs? Except for that, this could be a simple LEFT JOIN or even INNER JOIN between the two tables

Comment: The logic is that I need to identify what records from Table1 don't have a corresponding entry in Table 2 for each Type. So actually, I want to filter the Desired result set on those NULL values and present that in a report. Something like that

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
SELECT tmp.*, t2.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 t1a, (SELECT DISTINCT [Type] FROM Table2) t2a) tmp 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (tmp.Cluster = t2.Cluster AND tmp.OGE = t2.OGE AND tmp.Type = t2.Type)
```

And then only the results you need:

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 t1a, (SELECT DISTINCT [Type] FROM Table2) t2a) tmp 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (tmp.Cluster = t2.Cluster AND tmp.OGE = t2.OGE AND tmp.Type = t2.Type)
WHERE t2.Cluster IS NULL
```

---

*first (wrong) answer*

The desired seems to be something else than what you show in Desired-table?
It looks like the following query will do:

```
SELECT Table1.Cluster 
FROM Table1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.Cluster = Table2.Cluster AND Table1.OGE = Table2.OGE)
WHERE Table2.Cluster IS NULL
```

Comment: This will not work as it does not consider the Type.. So, in case we have 'OGE' B for 'Type' 44, it will not show that for type 'Liniar' the 'OGE' B does not exist.. This solution was also my first idea, but it is not the correct solution

Comment: @Andrey right, overlooked the Type... updated my answer.

Comment: I think this will work.. I was worried that it can be done only by using a Cross Join and then left join the result with Table2... Not sure if the Navision developement environment can be used to achieve this however as the Navision Queries are not so flexible as in SQL Server. But this is for sure a great solution..

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the values that match:

```
select og.cluster, og.OGE, t.type,
       t2.cluster, t2.OGE
from table1 og cross join
     (select distinct type form table2) t left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.cluster = og.cluster and
        t2.OGE = og.OGE and
        t2.type = t.type;
```